# Rails: server Side ajax-datatables-rails individual select input searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am fetching data from the server-side and using DataTables with JSON and AJAX, because I have about 20,000 rows. My framework is Ruby on Rails and I am using the ajax-datatables-rails gem to accomplish this. The DataTables is working perfectly, but I want to have select input so the user can select and filter by major if they chose to. I cannot figure out how to accomplish this, and I cannot seem to find any good resource on how to do this.

This is what I have so far:

**student.js**

```
var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: $('.datatable').data('source'),
    columns: [
        {data: "student_id"},
        {data: "first_name"},
        {data: "last_name"},
        {data: "major"},
    ]
});
```

**datatables/student_datatable.rb**

```
class StudentDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

  def view_columns
    @view_columns ||= {
      student_id:   { source: 'Student.student_id' },
      first_name:   { source: 'Student.first_name' },
      last_name:    { source: 'Student.last_name' },
      major:        { source: 'Student.major' },
    }
  end

  private

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {
        student_id: record.student_id,
        first_name: record.first_name,
        last_name:  record.last_name,
        major:      record.major,

      }
    end
  end
  def get_raw_records
    Click.all
  end
end
```

**students/index.html.erb**

```
<%= select_tag "major", options_for_select([ "CS", "BIO", "CIS", "PSY", "BUS" ]) %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails', github: 'jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails'
```

Comment: you can use https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_datatables for server side with awsome DSL for datatable

Comment: Do you know how to filter by major in my student table using this? Could you explain to me what is DSL?